# How can convert my PC to online server?

Tags: php, android, mysql, mysqli, server

I have made an android app that can connect to MySQL database via online server url. Now, I want to connect the app to MySQL database on my PC instead of the online server. I have searched the internet, and recommendations were to use No-IP software for Dynamic DNS and forward port 3306 in router's configuration page. then, use an online host like [000webhost.com](http://000webhost.com), I have done all of this, but I still don't know how to link my PC to the free domain I acquired on the internet? the input to my android app should be like

```
String ServerURL = "http://mydomain.000webhost.com/get_data.php" ;
```

I have the get_data.php file on my PC, how can I connect it to the online host.

**Update**
thank you alexandre for your help. I opened port 80 on my PC inbound/outbound rules, and this is my NAT page in the
[router config. page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v95dN.png), can you tell how should I fill these fields?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, does your provider allow you for incoming traffic on port 80? Then, you should create a NAT, on your router, redirecting all incoming traffic on port 80 to your PC.

Comment: I updated the question according to your answer. would you review the update please? kind regards

Comment: also I have wamp server, and this is the state of port 80 on its side,

Comment: ***** Test which uses port 80 *****
===== Tested by command netstat filtered on port 80 =====

Test for TCP
Your port 80 is used by a processus with PID = 9508
The processus of PID 9508 is 'httpd.exe' Session: Services
The service of PID 9508 for 'httpd.exe' is 'wampapache64'
This service is from Wampserver - It is correct

Test for TCPv6
Your port 80 is used by a processus with PID = 9508
The processus of PID 9508 is 'httpd.exe' Session: Services
The service of PID 9508 for 'httpd.exe' is 'wampapache64'
This service is from Wampserver - It is correct

Comment: ===== Tested by attempting to open a socket on port 80 =====

Your port 80 is actually used by :

Server: Apache/2.4.33 (Win64) PHP/5.6.35